# Proving (self) similarity with Mathematica - Reccurrence Plots, Similarity Plots etc

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis, proof

I posted this question in [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/213765/23593) but given the sheer tumultuous number of questions that keep appearing on math.se and also given that I am trying to accomplish this in Mathematica, I thought I'd post an alternate version of this question here. (I hope that's not totally unacceptable to quasi-reproduce my question from elsewhere). I do realize that I'll receive perhaps different flavors of an answer from math.se and mathematica.se.

Simply put, given two sets of data (Discrete Fourier transform matrices in this case), how do I prove similarity in the data.

[image]
[image]

Comparing the figure on the Left with that on the Right, I somehow have an inkling that theres similarity in the figures.

What I have is DFT data for these figures too (just the top left corner of the DFT data, with the DC component removed), which looks so:

[image]
[image]

The DFT corner on the left is for the contour plot on the left and the one on the right is for the contour plot on the right.

I did a bit of research and came up with these: [self similarity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similarity_matrix), [Smith Waterman algorithm for gene sequencing, it is implemented in Mathematica](http://www.med.nyu.edu/rcr/rcr/course/sim-sw.html) (also see ref/SmithWatermanSimilarity), and a somewhat [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1928/204) question posted on Mathematica.SE several months ago.

I understand that this is more math related than Math*ematica* related but as I'd like to use Mathematica since I pre and post process my data in it, I thought I'd ...ask! `:)`

I used the `MatrixPlot` to generate the plots from the data below.

### Here is DFT data for the figure on the **left**:

```
{{0, 0., 23.1306, 0., 4.63337, 0., 4.87462, 0., 1.13912, 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 59.8403, 0., 11.402, 0., 0., 
  0., 1.53024, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {23.3079, 0., 23.2309, 0., 3.80344, 0., 4.07117, 0., 1.07381, 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 11.3638, 0., 
  3.51212, 0., 4.17147, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0.}, {4.56479, 0., 3.80023, 0., 4.05799, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 4.1947, 0., 
  1.12046, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {5.12425, 0., 4.21734, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1.54858, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {1.07898, 0., 
  1.094, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}
```

### And data for the figure on the **right**:

```
{{0, 0., 0.940723, 0., 2.95705, 0., 2.92228, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 18.867, 0., 7.68905, 0., 0., 0., 
  1.61012, 0., 1.07367, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {1.28581, 0., 12.1276, 0., 6.00817, 0., 0., 0., 1.7524, 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 8.01748, 0., 14.725, 0., 
  0., 0., 1.05116, 0., 2.1411, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {2.77763, 0., 6.2871, 0., 1.82885, 0., 1.65436, 0., 1.43276, 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  3.54584, 0., 1.45959, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {3.11339, 0., 0., 0., 1.89853, 0., 3.24873, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1.83295, 0., 0., 0., 1.57703,
   0., 1.14208, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
  0., 1.61293, 0., 1.32478, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1.02113, 0., 2.18193, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.976133, 0., 
  0.931741, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}
```

Comment: May be you can use fractal dimensions to measure the similarities. Also related post might help 'Measuring fractal dimension of natural objects from digital images' but mainly for images http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/measuring-fractal-dimension-of-natural-objects-from-digital-images

Comment: @s.s.o That is an interesting point you make. I considered this later in 2012 but dropped the idea entirely as I had to defend and finish my PhD! Perhaps I will do this on an other day to include in my lectures! `:)` Thank you for your answer/comment!

Answer (score 0):

> Simply put, given two sets of data (Discrete Fourier transform
> matrices in this case), how do I prove similarity in the data

Similarity of two arrays of data is not about comparing of their spectrum, but about computing *correlation*/*covarince* of the data.
In other words, you do not need to go into frequency domain - you should stay in the initial coordinate domain :-)
Just use corresponding Correlation/Covariance Mathemetica functions (matrix can be input too as well as regular lists - vectors), and you'll get smth like this:
[image]
[image]