# Measure perimeter of black edge in Mathematica

Tags: image-processing

I have a pattern like the one below. How could I measure the total length of the perimeter of the black/white edge? This would give me a measure of spatial frequency. Any tips would be great!

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/measuring-fractal-dimension-of-natural-objects-from-digital-images) is a good start

Comment: Matlab has a function that I think is similar, called bwperim: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit**

You should be aware that there are 2 basic ways of counting perimeter pixels: 4-ways neighbors or 8-ways neighbors. The difference is about whether counting or not the yellow pixels in this figure:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to count them, then almost manually:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jt0I.gif"]; 
mask = Complement[Partition[#, 3] & /@ ({0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0} - 
       RotateLeft[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, #] & /@ Range[9]), {Array[0 &, {3, 3}]}];
ip = ImagePad[i, 10, RGBColor[0.4980 {1, 1, 1}]];
is = Binarize@
  ImageSubtract[ HitMissTransform[ColorConvert[ip, "Grayscale"], mask, .1], 
   ImageSubtract[HitMissTransform[ColorConvert[ip, "Grayscale"], mask, .1], 
                 HitMissTransform[ColorConvert[ip, "Grayscale"], mask, .8]]]

ImageMeasurements[is, "Total"]
```

[image]

> 14715

If you don't want to count the diagonal neighbors, then we change the mask to consider only four neighbors per pixel:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jt0I.gif"];
mask = {{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1,  0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
        {{0,  0, 0}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, { 0, 1, 0}, {0,-1, 0}}};

ip = ImagePad[i, 10, RGBColor[0.4980 {1, 1, 1}]];
is = Binarize@
  ImageSubtract[ HitMissTransform[ColorConvert[ip, "Grayscale"], mask, .1], 
   ImageSubtract[HitMissTransform[ColorConvert[ip, "Grayscale"], mask, .1], 
                 HitMissTransform[ColorConvert[ip, "Grayscale"], mask, .8]]];

ImageMeasurements[is, "Total"]
```

> 10411

Comment: I think you should explain your code a little bit :) also, do you have an idea why there is quite huge difference between yours 14.7k and mine 13k?

Comment: if you worry about that difference we need to get into a discussion over what the exact answer should be. Do you want the length of the smooth curves or the length of the pixelated edges?

Comment: @george2079 It's more than that. Take a look at the last edit

Comment: @Kuba I deleted my previous comment. That isn't the reason. Still thinking.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not experienced in image processing so it may be naive but who knows :)

```
pro = EdgeDetect@pic 
pro// ImageData // Flatten // Count[#, 1] &
```

[image]

> ```
> 15683
> ```

Which is counts of white pixels, it can be first rough estimate of perimeter I think. Well that's just a shot :)

Since I'm a beginner I do not know how to hide outer circle which should not add to the counts. But:

```
 pro // ImageData // Dimensions
```

> ```
> {828, 828}
> ```

So I can calculate its perimeter :D and subtract from our result:

```
15683 - 828 Pi // N
```

> ```
> 13081.8
> ```

Comment: This is pretty good, thanks! I found that using MorphologicalPerimeter, the outer edge is not shown (although number of white pixels increase quite a bit)

Comment: @Levi I'm glad you like it :) If you find more precise method you can show it here for future visitors.

Comment: With Mma 9.0 `pro = EdgeDetect@Import@"http://i.stack.imgur.com/7jt0I.gif";
-828 Pi + (pro // ImageData // Flatten // Count[#, 1] &) // N` gives me **14339** ... very near my own answer

Comment: @belisarius I've copied this code and it gives me exactly the same value as in my answer. mma 9.0 win 7...

Comment: @Kuba Your machine is bewitched, for certain

Comment: I edited your image link to render it in a smaller format. Revert my change if you don't like it

Answer (score 10):

How about using

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jt0I.gif"];
comp=ClusteringComponents[img];
ComponentMeasurements[comp, "PerimeterLength"]

(*{1 -> 6392, 2 -> 16402, 3 -> 16364}*)
```

[image]

```
(*Here not only black/white transitions but all included not OP asked for!*)
```

**Edit 1**

Correction based on the comments below!

```
(*Towards the solution*)
(*Find and filter gray and black components*)
{compGray, compWhite} = {comp /. { 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0}, 
   comp /. { 1 -> 0, 3 -> 0}};
GraphicsRow [{Colorize[compGray] , Colorize[compWhite]}]
```

[image]

```
(*Convert to image*)
imgGray = ColorNegate@Binarize@(compGray // Image);
imgWhite = ColorNegate@Binarize@(compWhite // Image);
(*Find bounding circle information*)
circleInfo = ComponentMeasurements[imgGray,
   {"BoundingDiskCenter",
    "BoundingDiskRadius"}][[All, 2]]
```

circle Center and radius

> {{{414.499, 413.501}, 413.999}}

-

```
(*Detect edges of white components*)
edges = Closing[EdgeDetect[imgWhite], 2];
(*Subtract the bounding circle from curves of white component*)
iCurves = Rasterize[Show[{edges,
    Graphics[{Black, Thickness[0.003],
      Circle @@ # & /@ circleInfo}]}]]
```

[image]

```
(*Calculate the total perimeter*)
ImageMeasurements[Thinning@Binarize@iCurves, "Total"]
```

The result

> 10358

Comment: The exterior circle boundary should not be counted. Only black/white transitions

Comment: Arrgh! I see now... I'll try to correct it.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another simple solution: As @belsarius pointed out, there's a big difference between 4- and 8-neighborhood. I'll use 4-neighborhood:

```
neighborhood = DiamondMatrix[1];
ArrayPlot[neighborhood, Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

You can use `BoxMatrix[1]` for 8-neighborhood.

Now I'm going to use the fact that if I dilate the original image with this neighborhood (mask), then every border pixel is changed to white (because that's the brightest color in the neighborhood):

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jt0I.gif"], "Grayscale"];
dilated = Dilation[img, neighborhood];
```

So I'm looking for the pixels that are black in the original image and white in the dilated image:

```
eps = 10^-5;
borderPixel = 
  Function[{pixel, dilated}, 
   If[pixel < eps && dilated > 1 - eps, 1, 0], {Listable}];
border = borderPixel[ImageData[img], ImageData[dilated]];
```

Then `Total[border, 2]` gives the number of border pixels:

> 10422

I'm not sure why this number is different from @belisarius' result.

**EDIT:**

Ah, I think I've found the difference: I'm counting black pixels that have at least one white pixel in their neighborhood. And find 10422 of those. If I count *white* pixels that have at least one *black* pixel in the neighborhood, I get 10411 pixels:

```
eroded = Erosion[img, neighborhood];
eps = 10^-5;
borderPixel = 
  Function[{pixel, eroded}, 
   If[pixel > 1 - eps && eroded < eps, 1, 0], {Listable}];
border = borderPixel[ImageData[img], ImageData[eroded ]];
```

I don't know which one Levi is looking for

Comment: Are the white pixels extended 1 px outwards of the fictive circle?

Comment: @s.s.o: Yes, the white pixels are extended over the borders. But `borderPixels` checks if a pixels is white in the dilated image *and* black in the original. So I don't have to worry about pixels that aren't black in the original image.

Comment: It's now clearer to me. Thank you!

Comment: Why so big diffrence to me?

Comment: @yode: I think it's because you use `Dilation[..., 1]`, which uses `BoxMatrix[1]` as structuring element - meaning, you're using an 8-neighborhood, where I use a 4-neighborhood

Answer (score 2):

```
mm = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jt0I.gif"];
mult = ImageSubtract[MorphologicalPerimeter[Binarize[mm, {0, 0.0001}]], 
  Dilation[MorphologicalPerimeter[Binarize[mm, {0.4, 0.5}]], 1]]
```

[image]

```
ImageMeasurements[mult, "Total"]
```

> 14714.