# Fractal dimension of a large networked molecular system

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, graphics3d, numerics

I am trying to determine the fractal dimension of this complex biomolecule (figure attached). Any clues as to how this can be done. In trying to determine this quantity, I wonder how its SecondaryStructure can be visualized. So there are 2 issues: 1) Visualizing its secondary structure, and 2) Determine its fractal dimension. Answer to One or both questions is appreciated.

```
Import["http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=pdb&compression=NO&structureId=2INU", "PDB", ImageSize -> Medium]

Import["http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=pdb&compression=NO&structureId=2INU", {"PDB", "SecondaryStructure"}]

Import["http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat= pdb&compression=NO&structureId=2INU", {"PDB", "ResidueChainLabels"}]
```

[image]

Comment: How do you define fractal dimension (notice that for a physical system this is not a trivial question at all)? What is "secondary structure"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_secondary_structure gives a description of secondary structure which has to do with base pairs within the molecular system. This option is provided within MMA-10

Comment: http://subutu-ap.eng.hokudai.ac.jp/nakayama/pdf/Reviews_of_Modern_Physics_Vol.66_No.2_pp.381-443(1994).pdf  provides a good source of quantifying the fractal dimension of this biomolecule, assuming that we consider that it is made up of networked nodes etc......I admit that this is not an easy problem, maybe an earlier query http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/measuring-fractal-dimension-of-natural-objects-from-digital-images/39302#39302 may be useful....so we map an image of the biomolecule & measure its fractal dimension via this method

Comment: When you have two distinct questions it is generally better to ask them separately. The site is easier for people to use that way (eg a future user looking for how to visualize secondary structure might overlook a question which appears to be about fractal dimensions). Also, you can only accept one answer, so what will you do if you get awesome but separate answers to both questions?

Comment: @Woods Fair enough, valid point....will try to carve out the question into two soon.

Comment: It might be best to leave it as it is now, since there is an answer which appears to address both questions.

Comment: @Woods I'll leave the question as it as suggested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mathematica should render the secondary structure in the usual way when you import pdb files. I dont know why this doesn't work with the example you provided. I thought there might be a size limit for the protein but I managed to import much bigger proteins such as **1YHU** and they got rendered without problems... strange.

```
Import["http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/download/downloadFile.do?fileFormat=\
    pdb&compression=NO&structureId=1YHU", "PDB"]
```

> [image]

I don't know how fractal dimensions of biomolecules are usually calculated but simple box counting is always an option. The box counting dimension of an image can easily be determined by using `ImagePartition` as done in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/measuring-fractal-dimension-of-natural-objects-from-digital-images). The algorithm can easily be applied to 3D images.

This reduces the problem to the generation of a 3D image from the protein data. I though it was more convinient to use the *mol2* format because Mathematica should allow the import of `EdgeRules` for this format. Anyways, I couldn't get that to work and I ended up extracting the `VertexCoordinates` and `EdgeRules` by pattern matching.

```
data = Import["../2DSP1.mol2", "Lines"];

StringSplit[#] & /@ 
   StringCases[data, DigitCharacter .. ~~ ___ ~~ "1.000"] //. {} -> 
   Sequence[];
coord = ToExpression@Flatten[%, 1][[All, 3 ;; 5]];
StringSplit[#] & /@ 
   StringCases[data, 
    DigitCharacter .. ~~ Whitespace ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ 
     Whitespace ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ Whitespace ~~ 
     DigitCharacter ..] //. {} -> Sequence[];
edgeRules = ToExpression@Rest@Flatten[%, 1][[All, 2 ;; 3]];

Graphics3D[Line[{coord[[#1]], coord[[#2]]}] & @@@ edgeRules]
```

> [image]

The conversion to `Image3D` was done by populating a SparseArray with points along the connection network. This can definitely be improved but you get the idea. The current implementation takes a lot of memory!

```
ranges = {Floor@Min[#], Ceiling@Max[#]} & /@ Transpose[coord];
scaling = 8;
Image3DDim = scaling (#2 - #1) & @@@ ranges;
lin = LinearSolve[{{ranges[[#, 1]], 1}, {ranges[[#, 2]], 1}}, {1, 
      Image3DDim[[#]]}] & /@ Range[3];

raster = 20;
rasterPoints = 
  Flatten[Table[
      coord[[#1]] - (coord[[#1]] - coord[[#2]])/raster*a, {a, 0, 
       raster}] & @@@ edgeRules, 1];
res = DeleteDuplicates@
   Transpose@
    Flatten[{Round[
         lin[[#, 1]] rasterPoints[[All, #]] + lin[[#, 2]]] & /@ 
       Range[3]}, 1];

i = Image3D[SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ res],"Bit", 
  ColorFunction -> "WhiteBlackOpacity", Boxed -> True]
```

> [image]

The box counting code gives as a fractal dimension of ~1.6.

```
MinS = Floor[Min[ImageDimensions[i]]/2];
data = ParallelTable[{1/size, 
    Total[Sign /@ (Total[#, 3] & /@ (ImageData /@ 
          Flatten[ImagePartition[i, size]]))]}, {size, 5, MinS/2, 5}];

line = Fit[Log[data], {1, x}, x]
Plot[line, {x, -4.5, -2}, Epilog -> Point[Log[data]], Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

> 11.2048 + 1.61623 x
>
> [image]

Comment: Nice post :) +1

Comment: i have a set of points in 3-dimensions and i want to extend this code can you help me ?