# Renyi dimension

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the Renyi dimension.

I have found a package in the book of Baumann — *Mathematica for Theoretical Physics II*. The problem is that the code does not work.

I want to plot the $D_q$. I tried with the code reported below.

```
Dq[p_List, r_List] := 
  Block[{l1, l2, listrg = {}},
    (*----length of the lists---*)l1 = Length[p];
    l2 = Length[r];
    If[l1 == l2,
      (*----variation of q and determination of D_q---*)
      Do[
        gl1 = Sum[p[[j]]^q r[[j]]^((q - l1) Dfractal), {j, 1, 11}] - 1;
        result = FindRoot[gl1 == 0, { Dfractal, -3, 3}];
        result = -Dfractal /. result;
        (*----collect the results in a list---*)
        AppendTo[listrg, {q, result}], 
        {q, -10, 10, .101}], 
      Print[" "];
      Print[" Lengths of lists are different!" ];
      listrg = {}];
    listrg]

    ListDq = Dq[p, r];
    ListPlot[listDq, AxesLabel {"q", "Dq"}]
```

I can specify values for `p` and `r`. For instance `p = {1/5, 3/5, 1/5}` and `r = {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}`.

The problem is probably to set the values of `p` and `r`. They should be the probabilities and the size of the boxes. Any ideas?

Comment: We can not help you at all without the code and the description of the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to do the same, as in this question? [Measuring fractal dimension of natural objects from digital images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/measuring-fractal-dimension-of-natural-objects-from-digital-images/125350#125350)

Comment: Looking at the code I transferred to this question from yout answer post, it won't work because you have specified that 'p` and `r` must have length 11 and your example `p` and `r` are too short.

Comment: Too short? Why? How can I change it?

Comment: @Spook82 you are doing `Sum[p[[j]]^q r[[j]]^((q - l1) Dfractal), {j, 1, 11}]` the index `j` goes from 1 to 11 and `p` and `r` have only 3 items. BTW, Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] the question if improvable, **don't add to the question in the comments or the answers section**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers.  The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back** .

Comment: I understand the problem. Also with this modification, the code does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly debugged code.

```
Dq[p_List, r_List] := 
 Block[{l1, l2, listrg = {}},(*----length of the lists---*)
  l1 = Length[p];
  l2 = Length[r];
  If[l1 == l2,(*----variation of q and determination of D_q---*)
   Do[
    gl1 = 
     Sum[p[[j]]^q r[[j]]^((q - l1) Dfractal), {j, 1, l1}] - 1;
    result = FindRoot[gl1 == 0, {Dfractal, -3, 3}];
    result = -Dfractal /. result;
    (*----collect the results in a list---*)

    AppendTo[listrg, {q, result}]
    , {q, -10, 10, .101}],
   Print[" "];
   Print[" Lengths of lists are different!"];
   listrg = {}];
  listrg]


p = {1/5, 3/5, 1/5};
r = {1/2, 1/2, 1/2};
ListDq = Dq[p, r];
ListPlot[ListDq, AxesLabel -> {"q", "Dq"}]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Do you know how to exclude a point in ListLinePlo[]t? In this case Exclusions does not work. I would like to exclude the point q=1 where there is a singularity.

Comment: See `Drop` or `Delete`?

Comment: The modification of the code implies several mathematical problems. The plot is no longer Dq. It looks like that you cannot change $l1$ with $Min[Length[p], Length[r]]$. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit in a hurry when I wrote that. I just wanted to point out that you used the number `11` (eleven) where it should have been something dependend on the length of the input data (e.g. `l1` ("ell" "one").